# What is a reasonable Epsilon/Tolerance value for this image scaling code?

Tags: c#, image, resharper, precision, image-scaling

Resharper wants me to change this existing code:

```
if (pic.Height == oldH)
{
    pic.Height *= fX;
}
```

...to this:

```
if (Math.Abs(pic.Height - oldH) < TOLERANCE)
{
    pic.Height *= fX;
}
```

...because "*Comparison of floating point numbers with equality operator. Possible loss of precision while rounding values*"

The "guttersnipe" (the tooltip that pops up when hovering over Resharper's light bulb icon to the left of the code) is "*Fix floating point numbers comparing. Compare a difference with Epsilon*"

The code has worked for months without problems; I'm glad to make it better by using the Resharpened version of the code but: what should the value of the Epsilon ("TOLERANCE") be?

Here is the code in full:

```
internal static void ScalePicture(Picture pic, double width, double height)
{
    var fX = width / pic.Width;
    var fY = height / pic.Height;
    var oldH = pic.Height;
    if (fX < fY)
    {
        pic.Width *= fX;
        if (pic.Height == oldH)
        {
            pic.Height *= fX;
        }
        pic.Top += (height - pic.Height) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        pic.Width *= fY;
        if (pic.Height == oldH)
        {
            pic.Height *= fY;
        }
        pic.Left += (width - pic.Width) / 2;
    }
}
```

Would something like this be reasonable:

```
const double TOLERANCE = 0.001;
```

?

Note: Consistently, R# also wants the second "if (pic.Height == oldH)" to be compared to TOLERANCE.

Comment: What about [Double.Epsilon - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Sounds reasonable; this human/space being will go with that, at least for the time being.

Comment: I'm missing something obvious, but how can `oldH` change between where you assign `pic.Height` to it and where you test it for equality against `pic.Height` ? That is, aren't these equality tests always `true` ?

Comment: Good point; I got this code from elsewhere; perhaps the answer is that the equality test is more persnickety; e.g., the assignment may assign 99.9999% of the value, or 100.0001 % of the value, and that slight variance may be detected by the equality test.

Comment: The page that I linked to in my answer actually recommends that you NOT use Double.Epsilon:  Because Epsilon defines the minimum expression of a positive value whose range is near zero, the margin of difference between two similar values must be greater than Epsilon. Typically, it is many times greater than Epsilon. Because of this, we recommend that you do not use Epsilon when comparing Double values for equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code for comparing doubles after doing some research on the web.

```
public static bool EqualInPercentRange(this double Value1, double Value2, long Units = 2) {
  long longValue1 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(Value1);
  long longValue2 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(Value2);
  //
  // If the signs are different, return false except for +0 and -0.
  //
  if ((longValue1 >> 63) != (longValue2 >> 63)) {
    //
    // ReSharper disable once CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator
    //
    return Value1 == Value2;
  }

  long diff = Math.Abs(longValue1 - longValue2);

  return diff <= Units;
}
```

Original Source on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

As you know, a float number can hold a real continuous value, in most cases when comparing continuous values, the values are considered as equal if the distance between them is smaller then a small threshold (epsilon) , obviously that is not the case with integers,
**The only reason resharper is showing this message is because you are comparing floats without a th (regarding continuously)**, **what you need to do is you need to change Picture's height and width properties to integers** (***there is no reason why image width/height properties type will be floats in the first place)*** **, 
do that instead of following resharper's autofix.**

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about what a reasonable tolerance is.  Picture/Image types can and do have double type properties, even for width and height.  All WPF controls use double x, y, width and height and this includes the Image classes as well.

Comment: it does answer the question, as i wrote in other words, in this case a reasonable tolerance is 0 , you dont need tolerance in this case because it is not a continuous values, any image type or control that uses double properties convert it to int in their inner implemantation, ther's no such thin as half a pixel, because the code above is the "inner implementation" one just needs to hold the properties in integers to make it work like it should.